# Undefined function 'Work_Days' in expression

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to run an access qry that uses a module to perform some calculations. When I run the code below I get undefined function in expression. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\User\Database.accdb;")
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "qryTest"
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Open qryTest. Check that it does not contain user defined functions and that it runs.

Comment: I have a module that the query references - Function Work_Days

Comment: That will not work outside of MS Access.

Comment: So there is no way around this?

Comment: Probably not. It depends on what work days does and whether you can rewrite it as pure sql.

Comment: I can use sql server for this unfortunetly.

Comment: Access uses sql, sql does not mean sql server, it means `Structured Query Language`

Comment: It just compares the difference between 2 dates

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14196/discussion-between-remou-and-user1342164)

Answer (score 0):

Some notes on getting work days in Access using SQL. This is set out in columns for the sake of notes.

```
SELECT t.Startdate,
    DateDiff("d",t.Startdate,Date())-(DateDiff("ww",t.Startdate,Date())*2) AS InaccurateWorkDays,
    DateDiff("ww",t.Startdate,Date()) AS WeekEndCount,
    Weekday(Date()) AS EndDateWeekDay,
    DateDiff("d",t.Startdate,Date()+1) Mod 7 AS Remainder,
    IIf([Remainder]>0,
            [WeekEndCount]+(([EndDateWeekDay]=7)*-0.5)
                          +(([EndDateWeekDay]=[Remainder])*-0.5)
                          +(([EndDateWeekDay]<[Remainder])*-1),
            [WeekEndCount]) AS WeekEndCountAdjusted,
    [WeekEndCountAdjusted]*2 AS WeekEndDays,
    (Date()-t.Startdate)-[WeekEndDays] AS WorkDays
FROM table t
```

Result

```
Startdate   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
01/07/2012  15  2   6   6   2.5 5   14
02/07/2012  14  2   6   5   2   4   14
03/07/2012  13  2   6   4   2   4   13
04/07/2012  12  2   6   3   2   4   12
05/07/2012  11  2   6   2   2   4   11
06/07/2012  10  2   6   1   2   4   10
07/07/2012  9   2   6   0   2   4   9
08/07/2012  10  1   6   6   1.5 3   9
12/07/2012  6   1   6   2   1   2   6
18/07/2012  2   0   6   3   0   0   2
```

1. InaccurateWorkDays
2. WeekEndCount
3. EndDateWeekDay
4. Remainder
5. WeekEndCountAdjusted
6. WeekEndDays
7. WorkDays

Based on code found here: http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=102&t=2510&p=13924